# Power BI: Add thousand separator using dax to matrix

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have the following column with two different kind of data formats. I want to show it in a matrix visual and add thousand separators using dax. I know it's not ideal but due to different requirements it has to be like this.

| Category | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| Euro | 1000 |
| Total Stock | 20000 |
| Euro | 500 |
| Total Stock | 4432423 |
| Euro | 23132 |
| Total Stock | 23423 |
| Euro | 3232 |
| Total Stock | 433 |
| Euro | 42424 |
| Total Stock | 12312 |
| Euro | 4545 |
| Total Stock | 32233 |

I created a measure for changing the format like the following:

```
Measure_Amount = 
Var varAmount = sum(table[Amount])
RETURN
SWITCH (
SELECTEDVALUE ( 'table'[Category] ),
"Total Stock", Format(varAmount, "#;-#;#"),
"Euro", Format(varAmount, "#€;-#€;#€"))
```

In short, it will change the format based on the Category column but it will be formated as text.
It will show like this in Power BI. I have added the Amount column as row just to show the difference.

[image]

I would like to add thousand separators in the measure but I don't know how? Can anybody help? The default way to click it in Power BI doesn't work since the measure is formatted as text now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about adding the thousands separator to the format strings?

```
Formatted_Amount = 
VAR varAmount =
    SUM ( 'table'[Amount] )
RETURN
    SWITCH (
        SELECTEDVALUE ( 'table'[Category] ),
        "Total Stock", FORMAT ( varAmount, "#,###" ),
        "Euro", FORMAT ( varAmount, "#,###€" )
    )
```

[image]

Comment: This wouldn't change the thousand separator for the whole number. It would only effect decimals like if I have a number: 45534,54. The format strings can change how many decimals and use , or . as a separator. But it doesn't add a dot like 45.534,54.

Comment: That's a misconception. As you can see from my screenshot, it can.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! I oversaw the comma and used a dot instead

Answer (score 0):

With the new power bi feature for Dynamic format strings there is a better solution now (although its currently still in preview)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-nz/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-dynamic-format-strings

So you could add a dynamic format string
Basically the same as Peters solution except you just

```
SWITCH (
    SELECTEDVALUE ( 'table'[Category] ),
    "Total Stock", "#,###",
    "Euro", "#,###€","#,###"
)
```

Peters solution would mean the measure data type would be a string which is not good when aggregating.

So by using the dynamic format string it would keep it a number and that way it would behave better when using the measure in different aggregation levels